# Printf Variable String Length Specifier

Tags: c, string

I have a struct that contains a string and a length:

```
typedef struct string {
  char* data;
  size_t len;
} string_t;
```

Which is all fine and dandy.  But, I want to be able to output the contents of this struct using a `printf`-like function.  `data` may not have a nul terminator (or have it in the wrong place), so I can't just use `%s`.  But the `%.*s` specifier requires an `int`, while I have a `size_t`.

So the question now is, how can I output the string using `printf`?

Comment: You can *convert* a `size_t` to an `int`, provided the value fits...

Comment: @KerrekSB Well if the length doesn't fit in an `int` that's going to be one interesting `printf` call :-)) Should check though since it could overflow.

Comment: If `data` might contain non-printable characters (like a null character), you don't want `%s` at all.  Write a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would just be to use *unformatted* output:

```
fwrite(x.data, 1, x.len, stdout);
```

This is actually bad form, since `fwrite` may not write everything, so it should be used in a loop;

```
for (size_t i, remaining = x.len;
     remaining > 0 && (i = fwrite(x.data, 1, remaining, stdout)) > 0;
     remaining -= i) {
}
```

 (Edit: `fwrite` does indeed write the entire requested range on success; looping is not needed.)

Be sure that `x.len` is no larger than `SIZE_T_MAX`.

Comment: But if I wanted to use something like snprintf, this wouldn't work as well.  While in that case I could just copy over the data, I'd rather be able to use other formatting specifiers (like `%i`).

Comment: @drderp: I don't understand. How would you use `snprintf`? You can use `memcpy` to write to a memory location rather than a file...

Comment: @KerrekSB if I wanted to create a string along with a number, I'd have to first use `memcpy` to copy over the string, and then use `snprintf` to output the number at the location I want.  Not as great as just doing it all in one go, I think...

Comment: @drderp: Yeah. Well, it depends whether you want to handle arbitrary data with null bytes. If not, formatted printing with `%.*s` is preferable.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ok, one more question: does `%.*s` ignore null bytes?

Comment: @JeremyRodi: No, printing *stops* at the first null byte.

Comment: @KerrekSB Maybe `SIZE_MAX` rather than `SIZE_T_MAX`

Comment: @chux: Maybe. I couldn't actually find it, nor did I look particularly hard. It's `(size_t)-1` in any case.

Comment: @KerrekSB Suggest instead SIZE_MAX is >= 65535 and an implementation-defined value.

Comment: "`fwrite` may not write everything, so it should be used in a loop..." — according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9389745 this is wrong.

Comment: @mk12: You're right. I must have been confusing `fwrite` and Posix `write`. Let me strike out that second part. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that your string doesn't have any embedded NUL characters in it, you can use the `%.*s` specifier after casting the `size_t` to an `int`:

```
string_t *s = ...;
printf("The string is: %.*s\n", (int)s->len, s->data);
```

That's also assuming that your string length is less than `INT_MAX`.  If you have a string longer than `INT_MAX`, then you have other problems (it will take quite a while to print out 2 billion characters, for one thing).

Comment: not very likely, but the OP *could* be targeting an embedded or historic device with 16-bit `int`

Comment: Is this really the best way to go about doing this?  When I first noted the behavior, my first question was "Why isn't it a `size_t` anyway?"

Comment: @JeremyRodi: Not sure, but my guess is that it uses `int` instead of `size_t` because it's for backwards compatibility with code that was written before the C language was standardized, before the type `size_t` even existed.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I output the string using printf?

In a single call?  You can't in any meaningful way, since you say you might have null terminators in strange places.  In general, if your buffer might contain unprintable characters, you'll need to figure out how you want to print (or not) those characters when outputting your string.  Write a loop, test each character, and print it (or not) as your logic dictates.