# How to detect read/write errors when using fread() and fwrite()?

Tags: c, file, file-io, fwrite, fread

In C I am trying to read/write to a file with `fread`/`fwrite()`.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389669/do-fread-and-fwrite-have-failure-how-to-handle-this) answer i can use `ferror()` and `feof()` to check for errors.

My question is, how can I use them to do this?

Comment: Reading documentation and tutorials will lead you to answers much faster. This question is too broad.

Comment: @thebusybee Yes, reading the doc is useful, yet the nuances are not that easy to decipher and benefit with knowable assistance.

Comment: Just look at how complicated the answers (and the comments) have gotten!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic recipe is

```
size_t r = fread(buf, m, n, fp);
if(r > 0)
    success;
else if(ferror(fp))
    handle error condition;
else
    handle EOF condition;
```

Basically, in this case, a 0 return from `fread` means "either EOF or error", and you have to do something else to figure out which.  The "something else" is that `feof(fp)` is true if there was an EOF, and `ferror(fp)` is true if there was an error.  (Whether it's possible to have *both* an EOF and error condition at the same time is an interesting question which I am not going to try to answer.)

But, it's true, having *both* `feof()` and `ferror()` available is, mildly, overkill.  Typically you only need one or the other.  In the code fragment above I used `ferror` but not `feof`.  Obviously I could have arranged it a different way:

```
if(r > 0)
    success;
else if(feof(fp))
    handle EOF condition;
else
    handle error condition;
```

The other thing to remember, as @chux dicusses in his answer (and I got confused on in a previous version of this answer) is that `fread` can return less than you asked for.  So it's not an error for `fread` to return a value less than `n`, but greater than 0 — and this indicates that you've probably hit end-of-file (and `feof(fp)` would be true).

Things are a little different for `fwrite`, which returns `n` on success or 0 on total failure.  Theoretically, `fwrite` can return a number greater than 0 but less than `n`, and this would indicate, I guess, that it successfully wrote some number of items before it hit an error, but I don't know if that case ever actually happens in practice.

Comment: I'd use `if (r == n)` for success, since a short read might be indicative of an error of some kind.

Comment: @Shawn If you've set things up correctly, 0 < `r` < `n` is always a possibility but rarely if ever an error.  If you're reading, say, characters from a text file (with `m = 1`), you'll usually get a partial read at end-of-file.  If you're reading multibyte records, a partial read would indeed be erroneous, but in that case you should be using a value of `m` greater than 0, and matching your record size, meaning that you can read one or more full records, but still never a partial one.

Comment: Consider reading multiple multi-byte records in one go and having a partial one at the end of the file. You're expecting to read m records but get m-1. Application level error if not an actual low level input error, but still something that needs to be addressed.

Comment: @Shawn I do consider that case, but I honestly don't know how best to address it.  You may be expecting multi-byte records but not knowing how many to expect.  If `m > 1`, it's difficult or impossible to know if there was a partial record.  If you're reading multibyte records, and calling `fread` with `m > 1`, I doubt there's a good way to detect partial records. If you're reading multibyte records with `m = 1`, you can detect the partial records, but (a) it strikes me as not being the way `fread` was intended to be used, and (b) the success test might well be `r % recsize == 0`, not `r == n`.

Comment: Hi this was a few days ago but i have one last question, when you said ```it's true, having both feof() and ferror() available is, mildly, overkill. Typically you only need one or the other``` why is this? why is it an overkill to have both? would it suffice to have only ```ferror```?

Comment: @programme3219873 That sentence didn't mean much, actually.  *If* it were true that `fread` could fail for exactly one of two reasons, then theoretically you wouldn't need two functions to tell which was which, you could just have one, like maybe just `ferror()`, and then if `ferror` returned false, you'd know that the "problem" was that you'd hit EOF.  But, in fact, it's more complicated than that, because it's possible for both `feof()` and `ferror()` to return true at the same time, and conceivably you might want to detect and handle that case specially.

Comment: In any case, redundancy isn't necessarily bad: for instance, C bas both `for` and `while` loops, even though theoretically you'd only need one, since you can always simulate one in terms of the other.

Answer (score 1):

[@Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73250526/2410359) well covers the common cases with code like:

```
if (r > 0)
    success;
else if (feof(fp))
    handle EOF condition;
else
    handle error condition;
```

But we could dig deeper into:

```
size_t fread(void * restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE * restrict stream);
size_t fwrite(const void * restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE * restrict stream);
```

1. `fread()/fwrite()` returns 0 in 4 cases:
   1.1. An end-of-file just occurred. (`fread()` only)
   1.2. An end-of-file had occurred prior.  (`fread()` only)
   1.3. A read/write error just occurred (e.g. reading a file opened in write only mode or visa-versa, a read parity error, etc.)
   1.4. `size` or `nmemb` is zero.
2. Prior to the `fread()/fwrite()` call, the `stream`, which has 2 internal flags: *end-of-file* and *error* indicators, zero, either one or both of these may be set and are reflected in `feof()` and `ferror()`.  Commonly these are both clear before the `fread()/fwrite()` call, but not always.
3. Sometimes the amount of data desired to be read/written is less than requested.

Putting this together for `fread()/fwrite()`

```
size_t count = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream); // or fwrite
if (count == 0) {
  if (feof(stream)) {
    puts("End-of-file.");
  } else if (ferror(stream)) {
    puts("Stream error.");
  } else {
    puts("Request size 0.");  // Case not expected if size, nmemb are both > 0.
  }
} else if (count < nmemb) {
  puts("Less than expected data read/written.");
} else {
  puts("Success.");
}
```

There is value in checking `feof()` before `ferror()` as when the error indicator is set and `fread()` returns 0 due to end-of-file, the correct failure reason is reported.  Note that `fread()/fwrite()` do not return 0 if the *error indicator* is set.  They will return 0 if an error is just then detected and then set the error indicator.

Comment: I disagree that you should check `feof` before `ferror`. The only reason for both `feof` and `ferror` to return true at the same time, and order matter, is if end of file is reached and a previous read had an uncaught error. In that case, by checking `ferror` first you will lose the knowledge that eof was reached, but you will have the chance to handle the error. A silent error is in my opinion *always* worse than a silent eof.

Comment: @HAL9000 Your assertion is certainly at least reasonable - to report a prior error over the current end-of-file situation owing to its supposed graver concern - even though I disagree, I find it insightful.  I do not see as idiomatic C. If coder does not clear clear/handle the error prior to the I/O call, code should trust the coder to be doing what the coder wants and not out-guess the coder's goal.  [Trust the programmer](https://beza1e1.tuxen.de/articles/spirit_of_c.html). IAC, testing issues such as these is challenging in C as creating a sporadic I/O error lacks a C specified approach.

Comment: Yes, I agree in the idea of "Trust the programmer". If you do that, and trust that the programmer has handled all previous io-errors, then testing `feof` rather than `ferror` is just a matter of style. To summarize: Doing it one way or the other, *only* matters if there is a bug in the program, and in that case, signaling any error is better than signaling successful input processing. Especially since calling `ferror` rather than `feof` has virtually zero cost, both in runtime and programmer time (or any other metric you may think of).

Comment: "...or any other metric you may think of" -- Ok, maybe not in internet discussion time :-)

Comment: So, I have thought a little bit more.. What you are trying to say is that "If 'ferror` has been set before calling `fread`, that has a purpose, and don't try to question the programmers intentions, just do what you are told." Right? I can understand that kind of thought. Programs that try to act to smart are always a pain. I just don't think it is relevant in this case..

Comment: @HAL9000 Yes, my concern is more of the [that has a purpose, and don't try to question the programmers intentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73250385/how-to-detect-read-write-errors-when-using-fread-and-fwrite/73251064?noredirect=1#comment129386730_73251064) and so the current reading should report about the present case and not history.

Comment: @HAL9000 Note that `fread()`, `fgets()`, `fgetc()`, etc. do not return `EOF` if the stream error indicator is set prior to performing an input attempt.  I am following that standard library model.

Comment: Just to clarify why I think it is permissible to be smart in this case (So we can agree to disagree): Yes, "do what you are told" and "follow conventions" should both be holy mantras in c. But c has also the concept of undefined behaviour: If the programmer has broken or is about to break a contract, the implementation has the permission to do whatever it wants, even signal historic errors. Having the error bit set on a stream when passing it to a function is contract breakage in my opinion (at least I am going to document that in my functions from now on).  `clearerr` exist for a reason.

Comment: @HAL9000 "Having the error bit set on a stream when passing it to a function is contract breakage" --> I do not see that as UB for the C std lib.  IAC, these are generally rare and hard to test cases - so  documentation is good as to code's intent.

Comment: I don't claim that having error bit set when calling C std lib is contract breakage, just that I think it is reasonable to treat it that way in *my* functions. The reason is that after an IO-error the buffer is in an inconsistent state, and if another library function hasn't called `clearerr`, it is safe to assume that it hasn't fixed the buffer. And I am sure that reading with inconsistent buffers is some sort of contract breakage. I think APIs should be designed in such a way that any programming error is likely to trigger an abort down the line when not to much at odds with old conventions.